# jQuery .animation() delayed start

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a jquery animation where i want my header to hide (margin-top becomes negative) when I scroll down, and reappear **as soon as** I start scrolling up.
I was able to do this so far, but the problem is that the animation takes time to start!

here is my js code:

```
$(function(){
    headerOrgOffset = $('#topnav').height()
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
if (currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
    if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
        $("#header-wrap").animate({marginTop:'-40px'},200);
    } else {
        $("#header-wrap").animate({marginTop:'0px'},200);
    }
} 
previousScroll = currentScroll;
});
```

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8gHm/) for this

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean animation is taking time? when do you actually want it to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similiar to murdoch's answer, assuming that by saying animation is starting slow, you either want the animation to be very quick or you want it to start the moment you start scrolling

```js
var prevScroll;
var hidden = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (prevScroll) {
    console.log(currentScroll + "  " + prevScroll);
    console.log(hidden);
    if (currentScroll < prevScroll && hidden) {
      console.log('show');
      $("#header-wrap").animate({
        marginTop: '0px'
      }, 0);
      hidden = false;

    } else if (currentScroll > prevScroll && !hidden) {
      console.log(hidden);
      console.log('hiding');
      $("#header-wrap").animate({
        marginTop: '-40px'
      }, 0);
      hidden = true;
    }
  } else if (!hidden) {
    console.log('first time');
    $("#header-wrap").animate({
      marginTop: '-40px'
    }, 0);
    hidden = true;
  }
  prevScroll = currentScroll;
});
```

```css
#topnav {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 576px;
  bottom: 0;
}

#header-wrap {
  background: #f1f2f2;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <header id="header-wrap">
    <nav id="topnav">
      <!-- my nav options-->
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: To me, this is the best answer. It works the most reliably. For example, if I was to scroll down one "tick" of the mouse wheel and then back up, this works whereas the other answers don't.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I still haven't looked at the code, but the result at fiddle is what I need :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware that the scroll event is firing continuously as you scroll, not just once for down and once for up. So you have to ensure you only fire animate once in each direction.

I have modified your code to do this and it works well for me now, it uses a variable called hidden which records when the header is hidden, visible. And only fires animate once in each direction.

```js
$(function() {
  headerOrgOffset = $('#topnav').height()
});

var hidden = false;
var previousScroll = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
    if (currentScroll > previousScroll && !hidden) {
      hidden = true;
      $("#header-wrap").animate({
        marginTop: '-40px'
      }, 200);
    } else if (currentScroll <= previousScroll && hidden) {
      hidden = false;
      $("#header-wrap").animate({
        marginTop: '0px'
      }, 200, function() {
        state = '';
      });
    }
  }
  previousScroll = currentScroll;
});
```

```css
#topnav {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 576px;
  bottom: 0;
}

#header-wrap {
  background: #f1f2f2;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <header id="header-wrap">
    <nav id="topnav">
      <!-- my nav options-->
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialise `previouscroll = 0` first. only then the scroll event will take the `previousscroll` into account the first time window is scrolled

```js
$(function() {
  headerOrgOffset = $('#topnav').height();
  previousScroll = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
      if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
        $("#header-wrap").stop().animate({
          marginTop: '-40px'
        }, 200);
      } else {
        $("#header-wrap").stop().animate({
          marginTop: '0px'
        }, 200);
      }
    }
    previousScroll = currentScroll;
  });
});
```

```css
#topnav {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 576px;
  bottom: 0;
}

#header-wrap {
  background: #f1f2f2;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <header id="header-wrap">
    <nav id="topnav">
      <!-- my nav options-->
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```